# ORM/Persistence layer Advice

Tags: c#, .net, orm, persistence, poco

I'm starting a new project and I'm looking around for either a very good ORM or for a non-SQL-based persistence layer.
For this project, I really don't care on how the data is persisted, as long as it can be queried and stored with a reasonable speed and most importantly with simple queries.
Concurrency should be handled seamlessly (the front-end will be on another tier and there'll be several simultaneous users, although not necessarily working on the same data) and the less I have to focus on the data layer (easy queries, automatic lazy loading etc) the better.
I also want to avoid at all cost having to mess with string-based queries so tools supporting LINQ or otherwise intuitive and possibly strongly typed queries get a big bonus.
Finally working with POCO objects is another thing I'd really want to do
Here's a list of products I've evaluated and why they don't fit, just so that I don't see any advice about using those:

- NHibernate: crazy xml stuff, too much set up, high maintenance complexity and cost for model changes, session factories are messy and don't fit well with my needs
- Castle ActiveRecord: NHibernate based, little documentation plus some problems related to NHibernate still apply. Furthermore, to get decent models it takes so many attributes that one is better off creating the schema manually, and the way relations are handled is a shame.
- Linq To SQL: missing POCO objects and according to MS it won't improve much overtime (EF is what they're committed to)
- Entity Framweork: although in v4 POCO objects are possible, they're still pretty hacky and force you into doing too much manual work to set things up. Besides, v4 is just a beta
- LLBLGen Pro: good, especially with SelfServicing adapters, but not POCO. Also, the LINQ provider isn't perfect yet. Finally, deleting a group of objects is not possible via LINQ which results in mixing APIs (one of which is far from intuitive) and that I don't like.
- XPO: anything but intuitive, very slow, concurrency issues, not POCO
- SubSonic SimpleRepository: for a few minutes I thought I was dreaming. The deam came to an end as I figured out how the thing didn't handle relationships

I've also looked at MongoDB and CouchDB but in those cases the catches with related objects looked like they required too much testing before getting things right. Besides none of them offers strongly typed queries.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: This is a duplicate of a lot of questions.

Comment: but just in one big question :)

Comment: What did you finally go with?  I'm looking for something along these lines as well.  I've been looking at using CodeSmith and modified templates to just accelerate the ORM creation instead of applying a 'framework'/application.

Answer (score 7):

If you can afford LLBLGen license, go for it.

I seriously don't like LINQ query-syntax the more I work with it (although I LOVE the language features related to it like Extension Methods and Expression Trees).

I loved at first like everybody else, but being uncertain whether [[ where employee.Name.StartsWith("John Smit") ]] in that XYZ LINQ provider will be done in SQL statement or in LINQ to Objects (after the SQL returns all results), and whether [[ user.Roles.Contains(role) ]] will at all work or not is a big step behind.

LLBLGen can make deleting all items without loading them as easy as

```
MyEntityCollection.DeleteAll( new MyEntity {Condition = value} );
```

This is pretty simple and I like it. You get lazy loading and you set eager/deep loading by default and/or per query using Prefetch API. You can compose and construct dynamically (and easily) any filter/sort/loading at infinite levels. It's very nice.

There are only two problems about LLBLGen: first, it's price not all companies would love to pay especially given the hype Microsoft alternatives have. Second, the naming convention although standard in RDBMS theories) like PredicateFactory instead of "where" or "filter" and Prefetch instead of deep loading and even SortExpression instead of orderby, those all are a little scary to a developer working with it for the first times, but soon you learn to love them, given the power and ease they give. There are talks about POCO support in LLBLGen 3.0. I cannot tell about it because I don't know.

Now given I no longer work in a company that uses LLBLGen, the company uses LINQ to SQL mainly because it's "proven" in so many projects without big failures (unlike EF 1, which is lacking even LINQ features in LINQ to SQL and has very bad performance and can be quite limiting in advanced mapping - which it should be best for!). I used both in this company and hated both. The decision for new projects remained LINQ to SQL, and doing all we can to overcome it's limitations. This website StackOVerflow itself runs on top of it!!! You can work around it to do SEMI-POCO (you still need to use some L2S related types when it comes to associations).

I also do some small projects at home. Since I no longer have LLBLGen license, I decided to learn NHibernate and use it along with Fluent NHibernate and LINQ To NHibernate. I have learned through this that NHibernate is VERY strong. It changed how I work by some features like updating DB schema automatically (I never touched the D almost when using it). LINQ provider (in NHibernate Contrib project) is quite lacking sometimes but there is the unreleased source code of NHibernate itself contains a better LINQ provider (haven't tried it yet). The "Session" in NHibernate has problems when you are doing web development similar to those related to DataContext in L2S or ObjectContext in EF (LLBLGen doesn't suffer from those thanks to self tracking entities).

The biggest problems I had with NHibernate though was ability to find information. Too many pieces that should be put together in certain way and not much guidance can include advanced information for both mapping and querying. If not I had a friend (Tuna Toksoz , @tehlike on twitter) who happened to be a committer in NHibernate project source code, I'd really be in serious trouble.

The moral I learned was: If you want something that just works and a bit basic use Linq To Sql or SubSonic, if you want something in the middle and your production environment can afford BETA .NET version (given golive exists) use Entity Framework 4.0, if you want something very powerful and can afford the hard learning process go to NHibernate, AND, BEST OF ALL, if you can afford LLBLGen, USE IT.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but: I won't consider NHibernate in any of its flavors or products relying on it because of the little documentation and of the excessively complex architecture which I sure don't want or need to mess with. Limitations of the MS ORM solutions are something I'm well aware of so they really fall short of my needs and although as of now LLBLGen would be the preferred choice, I'm still hoping for something which keeps me and SQL in two worlds apart (even for schema creation)...

Comment: Wait a minute ... NHibernate has *little documentation*? Have you seen the material at http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html, or any of the myriad tutorials, etc.?

Comment: If you want to avoid strings as much as you can (mapping, querying), so you are choosing Fluent NHibernate and NHibernate Linq. This means you are going to find difficulties even choosing which versions to work with. See how many not-so-advanced mapping questions exist in Fluent NH mail group.

Comment: Another example is that I have using what most LINQ To NHibernate use, the Linq provider from NH Contrib, until only my friend mentioned that the current Trunk of NH has another Linq provider. Another issue is managing long-living entieis in web applications (say objects in ASP.NET SessionState) when applying the NH-Session-per-web_request pattern, in this case most examples you'll find are All-Or-Nothing ones like "S#arp Architecture" or very little guidance, and in general having to check multiple places for each area for documentation...

Comment: Note that -as I mentioned above- for my own code-at-home projects (including commerical ones), I'll most probably be using Nhibernate for any future ones, and I already use it in a current one, but still, I believe it'll be very hard to go to my team leader and convince him to use it in a project, except if we guarantee no one except the two of us will ever work on that project, which is never the case of course because it makes us unneessary dependencies as you sure agree.

Comment: You are right, LLBLGen Pro is a dream come true, the support is top-notch and the productivity boost is extreem.

Comment: @emaster70 if you want something that can generate your DB schema you should heading towards NHibernate (Entity framework 4.0 should have this, but...). I think I read something about LLBLGen 3.0 support for POCO (which MAY be generating schema) btut I'm sure I where I may have read that, but 3.0 is not available today anwyay also. So, for that specific reason, you'd go for NHibernate.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [DataObjects.Net](http://dataobjects.net):

Advantages:

- Easy to design business model using simple classes and attributes
- Database schema is automatically generated in runtime - so you don't have to care on how data is persisted
- Automatic lazy loading, transparent persistence, etc...
- Really good LINQ implementation
- High performance

Disadvantages:

- Not POCO

Answer (score 4):

With all respect, I tend to absolutely disagree with your assessment of NHibernate weaknesses.

I think XML mappings are extremely simple and intuitive to create.
Adding reference to NHibernate.dll and creating SessionFactory is a piece of cake too.
Maintenance and change management is significantly simplified.
Session Factories and Sessions are very easy to understand and deal with.

Overall I think you're being emotional and not rational with your assessment.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Plus you don't HAVE to use XML mappings if you don't want to. FluentNhibernate has AutoMappings which are really useful for the simple projects. 

People don't really give NHibernate the chance it deserves. The "it's too hard" argument really doesn't hold true... at all.

Comment: Not only your post doesn't consider the poor (and I'm being kind here) documentation, but also it expresses a totally subjective POV whereas my point stands still: if I have to maintain mappings to a model then each change is more expensive and the places where bugs might show up doubles. So I admit I don't *like* the thing but still there're plenty of weaknesses.I don't want to study a whole framework to get persistence, it's overkill for what I need. And while FluentNhibernate may simplify things for model setup (still requiring more time than I wanna spend) things aren't still smooth enough

Comment: @emaster70 - you should probably edit your question to make it clear you don't want a tool that requires you to maintain O/R mappings yourself.

Comment: @emaster70 for me the online manual and http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html and the book NHibernate in Action http://www.manning.com/kuate/ is plenty documentation. 0-maintenance ORM is impossible, unless your DB schema is created by ORM (possible with NH and Fluent NH's AutoMappings)

Comment: We use NHib successfully but I have to agree with the original poster-the learning curve is steep, the doc. is substandard and there is significant overhead involved in maintaining the mapping files (Fluent does help with this). If what you want is transparent persistence NHib is not the right product. Things are improving and the community is supportive for both NHib and Fluent, but virtually everyone I know that is using NHib has spent a lot time writing a layer to simplify it or uses something like code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture. See post below about Telrik ORM.

Comment: There's no such thing as transparent persistence. It's impossible, unless you're on personal project where you're free to shape the DB the way you want regardless of cost, risk etc.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about using an object oriented database such as [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/). Although I have never used it, I found it quite interesting when I discovered it:

It supports LINQ querying, uses POCOs, and if I understood correctly, the data is simply stored in a file (no installation of a database is required).

Some links: [tutorial](http://developer.db4o.com/Resources/view.aspx/Formula_One_Tutorial/Tutorial_.NET_Version), [forum post](http://developer.db4o.com/forums/permalink/57354/57348/ShowThread.aspx#57348)

Comment: db4o would've been great if it hadn't been designed to be embedded, so concurrent usage of db4o is just a hack that came at some point and never really fit :( +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

LLBLGen.

If you think your going to find something that ticks all your boxes then you could be waiting for a long time.

Comment: I'm not hoping for something fitting 100%, just hoping to hear about something I couldn't find which gets very close to my needs. As I wrote in another comment, LLBL is nice but it still has a lot of limitations and small issues I'd rather live without.

Comment: LlblGen Adapter is the way I'de go , then I would use the poco template set, which provides translation from and to plain old clr objects

Answer (score 2):

**Write your own ORM**

It might sound crazy but you can write your own ORM. Sometime back in a project the client did not want to use 3rd party tools or libraries and for that reason, we ended up writing our own ORM which served specific objectives for us. You can decorate your objects' classes and properties with Attributes to map them with Database tables and fields. Have base class for all the business objects and do database operations on the objects using reflection.

This way you can build your own tiny ORM to suit the particular objectives you want.For your reference It may somewhat look like this.

```
[TableMapping("Users", "User", "Users")]
public class User : EntityBase
{
    #region Constructor(s)
    public User()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    #region Default Properties - Direct Field Mapping using DataFieldMappingAttribute

    private System.Int32 _UserId;

    private System.String _UserName;

    [DataFieldMapping("UserID")]
    [DataObjectFieldAttribute(true, true, false)]
    [NotNullOrEmpty(Message = "UserID Is Required.")]
    public override int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserId;
        }
        set
        {
            _UserId = value;
        }
    }

    [DataFieldMapping("UserName")]
    [NotNullOrEmpty(Message = "Username Is Required.")]
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserName;
        }
        set
        {
            _UserName = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region One-To-Many Mappings
    #endregion

    #region Derived Properties
    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that'd probably be out of budged, plus nobody on our team is a SQL guru so we'd rather not mess with SQL at any stage. Manually creating the model is the maximum level of direct DB interaction we're willing to tolerate.

Answer (score 2):

I've used LLBLGenPro, NHibernate and a few Object Databases.

My first recommendation would be for NHibernate with FluentNhibernate to handle the mappings.

I found 90% of the difficulty related to using NHibernate was directly tied to the XML mappings. When I switched over the FluentNhibernate, the pain went away.

The other 10% of the difficulty is simply ignorance; I didn't understand it. And that's not NHibernate's fault.

LLBLGenPro: I have no idea what the Linq support is like now, but before Linq was supported it was a PITA to write queries. I read the docs and I got it, but my coworkers did not and complained endlessly about the complexities of prefetch paths and the like. Plus, like you said - not POCO. Add on the cost and I'd say it's way more trouble than it's worth.

If it's not a client-server architecture, I'd suggest db40. I used it on a small, private project and loved it. Easy to use. Great little object database.

Comment: +1 for Fluent NH. Even if you like XML mappings you can use the fluent NH automapper to create a basic xml skeleton, output it to files and then tweak from there. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EntitySpaces](http://www.entityspaces.net/). I can't recommend from my own personal experience, but it works great for one of my colleagues (who is not into sof...)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but not only that still involves a lot of messing with RDBMS but it also seems to be very much influenced/cluttered with concepts of how the data is stored, which is what I'd like to abstract away as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Aspectize [here](http://aspectize.com/content/DALTechnologyHome.aspx)

Comment: Very interesting, +1 :) Too bad it looks far from production-ready

Comment: Thx, for the +1, I Agree that the web-site is not finished but the tool is production with developers using it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer has turned out to be LLBLGen Pro. In addition to it's capabilities, you gain a dedicated support team who cares about helping you get your project working and should you discover a bug, in most cases, you'll get a fix in hours or days. This can't be minimized, as it allows you to continue your work rather than waiting for a release (months?) or fixing the bug yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Telerik ORM](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx).  I haven't used it in production but it was based on a Java ORM\ODB called POET that worked very well for me several years ago. Since it uses assembly enhancement it offers a much more transparent experience than some of the products you rejected above.

In terms of a pure ODB [FastObjects by Versant](http://www.versant.com/en_US/products/fastobjects) is probably worth a look.

Good luck - let us know what you decide to go with.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll make sure to evaluate that and let you know!